# how to compile c file using gcc and compile hpp using g++ in one project

Tags: c++, c, opencv, gcc, g++

I have C project needs to link opencv library, the c code must compile with gcc, if I compile the project using gcc then it report errors that opencv hpp header file must be compiled as C++. so, any possible to compile c files using gcc and compile hpp files using g++ in one project? or any way to solve my compile problem

I specified rules below in makefile,but it seems not work

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.hpp
    @echo "  COMPILE $(abspath $<)"
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c 
    @echo "  COMPILE $(abspath $<)"
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "  COMPILE $(abspath $<)"
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cc
    @echo "  COMPILE $(abspath $<)"
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: I don't know the details of opencv, but in general you don't *compile* header files. You *include* header files. And you cannot include a header that only supports C++ to a C source file that is compiled with a C compiler.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. You compile .cpp files with a C++ compiler, not headers. And if you have such files in your project, you should either compile it all as C++ with the `extern "C"` path, or alternatively compile the C++ part into a lib or dll which the C program can then link. So please answer why you must mix C and C++ in the first place.

Comment: the project is a large C project that compile whit gcc，I want to keep the compile way to avoid potential problems. and now, I want it link opencv library which is a  C++ library, this cause my the mix C and C++ issue

Comment: Then it sounds like you'll want to build that as a library to link separately, assuming the API for the library isn't relying on specific C++ features. Brief googling suggests that OpenCV was originally a C code base and you should still be able use a C API. https://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-OpenCV-for-C

Answer (score 2):

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.c 
    @echo "  COMPILE $(abspath $<)"
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Looks OK.

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @echo "  COMPILE $(abspath $<)"
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Not OK. That should be `CXXFLAGS` (for C++), not `CFLAGS` (for C).

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cc
    @echo "  COMPILE $(abspath $<)"
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Same as above. Plus, your project should use **either** .cc **or** .cpp, not both.

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.hpp
    @echo "  COMPILE $(abspath $<)"
    @mkdir -p $(OBJ_DIR)
    @$(CXX) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

.hpp files include C++ code, so that is where the error message comes from. But more importantly, header files are **included**, not compiled to object code, so this whole make rule makes no sense. Your project *should* work without it (unless you have a different problem elsewhere).

---

Your comments indicate that you are somewhat arbitrarily mixing C code compiled with GCC, C code compiled with G++, and C++ code compiled with G++. This is a **bad** idea and will give you all kinds of problems down the road. C++ and C are *somewhat* compatible, but different in minor details that can and *will* come back and bite you. If it's C, compile it as C. If it's C++, compile it as C++. If you want to interface the two, write interfacing code. Don't just mix the codebases.